# UIScrollView setContentOffset:animated must be used from main thread only

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, multithreading, uikit

I'm performing an action in tab bar, i.e. (when the button is tapped twice) it should perform,

```
[root.FeedTableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
```

but I'm unable to perform it in the,

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{  
 });
```

as nothing happens, so I tried using,

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
});
```

and it worked fine expect in this case the threading runtime error pops up.

Inspect the code below and suggest a remedy, for tackling this threading issue which happens at

> [root.FeedTableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];

```
(void)processBtn:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSLog(@"sender:%li",(long)sender.tag);

    if (self.selectedViewController==self.viewControllers[0] && sender.tag==1){

        NewsFeedViewController * root = [newsFeedSceneController.viewControllers firstObject];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{


    [root.FeedTableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            if(!root.isUpdatingTableView)

            [root.refreshControl endRefreshing];

        });

            });
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using queues? Your action method is called on the main thread unless you are calling this method yourself from somewhere else.

Comment: I suspect that endRefreshing is stoping the scrolling.  if you remove it (along with ALL of the dispatch_async code) does it fit the problem?

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan Had to use queues in with high priority, in order to handle the UI functionality even when handling action methods. This throughly documented in apple guidelines. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html

Comment: @HamzaIqbal you are right about using queues to distribute work for concurrency. But you are doing nothing in the processBtn action method except handling UI. Using dispatch_get_global_queue for doing performing UI updates is not right. It returns a background queue which is not suitable for UI update.

Comment: @JonRose spot on, but I have to perform refresh control in order to check for new posts in the feed. Any workaround using queues in order to solve this?

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan I know that's wrong, but the calling gcd in this case does no good, atleast dispatch_get_global_queue does the required i.e. (scrolls to the top and performs a refresh) but generates the purple runtime error.

Comment: As @JonRose pointed, try removing all the dispatches and check if isendRefreshing is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jon Rose noted, scroll view line:

`[root.FeedTableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];`

and UIrefreshcontrol line:

`[root.refreshControl endRefreshing];` were the main conflict.

All that needed to be done was to remove UIrefreshcontrol line and add non UI dependent line`[root RefreshView];`